# Contact Phone Numbers in Iphone 5s

Tags: contacts

My contact list does not display the entire phone number. It displays (xxx)XX... or if the contact has been named, it will show part of the person's name and then ... How do I set the phone to show the entire number? I would like to easily see the number. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to reduce the font size. Go to **Settings** -> **Display & Brightness** -> **Text Size** and drag the slider to the left.

[image]

Unfortunately, this will change the font size in all apps that support dynamic font sizes but as far as I know, there’s no other option that would solve your problem.